# DatasetNotFoundException - salesforce2hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, salesforce, hadoop2, hadoop-plugins

I am using **salesforce2hadoop** library for exporting data from salesforce to hadoop.

I am using the below command for the same.

```
sudo java -jar salesforce2hadoop-assembly-1.0.jar init -u myUsername -p myPassword -b /home/nfsuser/imports/salesforce -w /home/sanjay/Desktop/enterprise.wsdl -s /home/nfsuser/imports/salesforce/account Account
```

We are getting the below error:

> org.kitesdk.data.DatasetNotFoundException: Unknown dataset URI: 
>   /home/nfsuser/imports/salesforce/account. Check that JARs for null datasets are on the classpath.

Need help in above issue.

Here is link for the same https://github.com/datadudes/salesforce2hadoop

Answer (score 0):

-b Base path argument to download the sales force data is expected to be in either of below formats:

- hdfs://localhost/imports/salesforce
- file:///path/to/dir

Try giving this a try:

`sudo java -jar salesforce2hadoop-assembly-1.0.jar init -u myUsername -p myPassword -b **file://**/home/nfsuser/imports/salesforce -w /home/sanjay/Desktop/enterprise.wsdl -s /home/nfsuser/imports/salesforce/account Account`